# Phone seems to have WiFi connection, but loses connection to internet

Tags: wi-fi, 4.4-kitkat

It's a Cat B15Q, with Android 4.4.2, with most recent update as issued by Cat.
I think it started with the most recent update. Unfortunately, Cat's support site doesn't work (you can't submit questions), so maybe someone here knows.

The phone always has a decent connection to WiFi, according to the icon. But after a while (it can be an hour or just 5 minutes), it no longer connects to the internet. I observed this on three different WiFi networks. Disabling and enabling WiFi fixes the connection, for a while. I disabled all sleep and battery saving options, but to no avail. It's driving me mad!

Comment: Even in the middle of a WhatsApp conversation, after sending a message, this happens. So annoying.

Comment: The utter unpredictability is what makes this so annyoing: the connection can last for a few hours, and suddenly, it will only last a few seconds, every time after reconnecting. I see the following options now: 1) throwing the thing out of the window; 2) waiting for Lollipop; 3) waiting for Cyanogen Mod; 4) FORMAT C:

Comment: The behavior is also network dependent: at home, I never have this problem. But at work and at other locations, I have. Maybe because at home I have only one WiFi station and at the other locations, the network uses different ones and the phone has trouble switching between these stations? Just a wild guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of days ago, Cat came out with a system update for my phone. One of the items was something about fixing WiFi issues. It seems to be working!

Answer (score -1):

why don't you try to get your phone back to the factory settings. i would suggest you to back your data prior going ahead with Factory Reset.

Comment: Well, this is indeed what Cat Support (after I had finally been able to make contact) recommended: "do a factory data reset followed by a software update"

Hmm... let's see... this will take a lot of time and there is no guarantee for success. I'll wait a bit, maybe someone here has a better idea.

Comment: A couple of days ago, Cat came out with a system update for my phone. One of the items was something about fixing WiFi issues. So far, it seems to be working... If I don't see any problems within the next few days, I'll answer my own question.